# Detect Roximity iBeacon without Roximity SDK?

Tags: ios, sdk, ibeacon

We are looking at ordering some iBeacons from Roximity but I am not clear if we have to use the Roximity SDK with these beacons or if I can use the core location functionality?

The reason I am asking is that I do not want to get tied to their SDK and then have to always buy beacons from them.

I was able to get the UUID of the Roxmity beacon, but I do not know what the beacons "identifier" is, so in the case of this code:
`[[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:_uuid identifier:@"COM.TEST.APP"];`
I do not know what to put in place of `COM.TEST.APP`

Comment: I think what you are trying to say in that confusing title is that you want to be able to detect *any* manufacturers iBeacon and not just Roximity iBeacons, via the Roximity SDK.  Is that right?

Comment: Hmm, not necessarily, but either way. At the moment I can turn my phone into a beacon and do everything I need to do without using the Roximity SDK, so I don't think I need their SDK at all. The problem is I cannot detect the Roximity beacons with my existing code.

Comment: @Chris how did you get the proximity device's UUID?

Comment: Turns out all Roximity UUID's are either: 8deefbb9-f738-4297-8040-96668bb44281, 8DEEFBB9-F738-4297-8040-96668BB44281

Comment: What about the major,minor? Can I configure it? How? Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can configure the major, minor, or UUID of the beacon. You just have to find the existing major, minor, and UUID, and then have your app search for those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identifier you mention in this line of code does not affect the ability to detect an iBeacon, Roximity or otherwise:

```
[[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:_uuid identifier:@"COM.TEST.APP"];
```

The "COM.TEST.APP" identifier is just a reference string for you as an application programmer.  By using this same string when constructing a second region, you are telling iOS that these are the exact same region.  This is useful for canceling monitoring or ranging.  It is also useful for *replacing* one region with another using the CoreLocation APIS.

As long as you keep it consistent for these purposes, that string can be whatever you want.

As for the bigger question if you can use their beacons independently of their SDK, try detecting their beacon with my free [Locate for iBeacon](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-for-ibeacon/id738709014?mt=8) app in the AppStore.  You have to add the Roximity UUID to the configuration list, but once you do so, if the app is able to locate it, that means it is compatible with standard CoreLocation iBeacon APIs.

Comment: I actually used that app yesterday. Just tried it again, it doesn't see these beacons. Either I do not have their real UUIDs, or there is something else preventing detection.

Comment: @Chris, how did you figure out the UUID?  If you are not certain of the UUID, you can find it out for sure (assuming it is acting as a standard iBeacon) by using two other tools from Radius Networks -- ScanBeacon (for your Mac) or Locate for iBeacon for Android 4.3.  The reason these tools work is because both OSX Mavericks and Android allow you to see any iBeacon regardless of UUID.

Comment: Maybe I have the wrong UUIDs then. I used an iOS app to find them. I will have to upgrade to Mavericks before I can run ScanBeacon.

Comment: Got it. The "UUIDs" I was using were actually the "Identifier" values... not sure what that means. But I got the UUID using ScanBeacon for OSX and got the UUIDs and it worked. Thank You.

Answer (score 8):

I received some Roximity beacons yesterday, and used them successfully without the Roximity SDK. The UUID that our beacons had was:

`8DEEFBB9-F738-4297-8040-96668BB44281`

We found the UUID by scanning with a Mac app we wrote that finds any beacons in the local area. Simply create a `CLBeaconRegion` with that UUID and start ranging, and they should show up. Make sure you've removed the plastic isolator tab from the battery.

As @davidgyoung mentions below, the `identifier` parameter won't affect whether you can detect the beacons or not.

Comment: FYI, that is the same UUID that our beacons have, my guess is that all Roximity beacons have the same UUID and only the major/minor values are different.

Comment: btw james (also @Chris), FYI my app refused to detect my Roximity beacons with your above UUID string, however this one worked: 8deefbb9-f738-4297-8040-96668bb44281. Tearing my hair out for ages… Cheers, good luck to all else!